# How to know if user already gived permission to Facebook SDK before

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am creating an android application with facebookSDK login . If the user logs IN for the first time I register him into my database . For the second time , I directly parse his datas from the database.My question is , what is the best behaviour to check if the user is gonna logging for the first time or not . I mean, how to check if he already gived permission to facebookSDK before or not?

Comment: What do you store in your DB, the user credentials ? I hope you cypher them. If it's the second time he log in, his datas are stored in DB. So to know if it's the first time, check if the user is in your DB

Comment: yeh, that is what I thought about .. but is there a way or a predefined function that can do the work with facebook SDK without having to check my database ? question of optimization

Comment: You must never trust the client for security relevant things. Somebody may simulate your client and get sensitive information from the server this way.

Answer (score 0):

*I have actually developed something similar recently.*

Just make a login method which adds a new row in your db table if the user is not there. the login method will get a user that has logined to facebook already (doesnt mean he's already in your database. just he already go through the `FB` process).

Basically, if the user is not there just add the user to the db. else means he already signed in to your application.